Computing norm of a matrix with positive entries
Is there anything in Mathematica that can help me compute norm of a matrix with non-negative entries faster than Norm? Approach below works for matrix[1000], but too slow for matrix[100000]
matrix[d_] := Normalize /@ UpperTriangularize[ConstantArray[1., {d, d}]];
Norm@matrix[1000]

From the math here, I expect Norm@matrix[10^5] to be close to 262.99434, was curious to check how large approximation error is
predictedNorm[d_] := (
   phi[\[Lambda]_] := Sum[(-\[Lambda])^n/(n!)^2, {n, 0, Infinity}];
   l0 = \[Lambda] /. 
     First@FindRoot[phi[\[Lambda]] == 0, {\[Lambda], 1.4}, 
       WorkingPrecision -> 50, AccuracyGoal -> 20, 
       PrecisionGoal -> 20];
   Sqrt[d/l0]
   );
predictedNorm[100000] (* 262.99434901 *)


Since your triangular matrix M is dense enough, it is already very memory-demanding to store 100000 x 100000 matrix elements of MM* which are all needed to compute the norm. Since you already know the kernel function (in Math forum), I advise you to construct "linear transformation" M and M* acting on 100000 dim vector space, which is of managable size. Then, the norm of M, which is the largest eigenvalue of MM*,  is well estimated from the growth rate of repeated application of M and M* on random initial vector.

(Now I see this...) Right, what @A.Kato said.

You're not going top fit that matrix just anywhere. You need a specialized matrix-times-vector routine (and vice versa, for the case at hand). I won't show the simple confirmation tests I did, but these do the job.
matTimesVec[vec_] := Module[{dim = Length[vec]},
  Table[Total[vec[[j ;;]]]/Sqrt[(dim + 1. - j)]
   , {j, dim}]]

vecTimesMat[vec_] := Module[{dim = Length[vec]},
  Table[vec[[1 ;; j]] . (1/Sqrt[(dim + 1. - Range[j])])
   , {j, dim}]]

Now we do power iterations, in effect computing, for a random vector, updates of the form vec = Transpose[mat].mat.vec, using the fact that the transpose can instead be done as vec.mat. I've found this seems to stqabilize after a few iterations so I do 10 such. Then the norm is the square root of the penultimate vector over the last vector, in all positions not driven to zero.
In[159]:= siz = 10^4;
AbsoluteTiming[
 rvec = RandomReal[1, siz];
 Do[vlast = rvec;
  rvec = matTimesVec[rvec];
  rvec = vecTimesMat[rvec],
  10];
 Sqrt[rvec[[1 ;; 5]]/vlast[[1 ;; 5]]]
 ]

(* Out[160]= {3.9033, {83.1682, 83.1682, 83.1682, 83.1682, 83.1682}} *)

So 4 seconds to handle 10000. It's an O(n^2) algorithm so give several minutes for 10^5.
siz = 10^5;
Timing[
 rvec = RandomReal[1, siz];
 Do[vlast = rvec;
  rvec = matTimesVec[rvec];
  rvec = vecTimesMat[rvec],
  10];
 Sqrt[rvec[[1 ;; 5]]/vlast[[1 ;; 5]]]
 ]

(* {356.045, {262.995, 262.995, 262.995, 262.995, 262.995}} *)

